# Do we require a ROS2 installation to use rclpy?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rclpy is an API from ROS2. It is based on the C based rcl. Do we need to have a ROS2 installation on the machine where I want to use rclpy ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293872/do-we-require-a-ros2-installation-to-use-rclpy-?/) by [vishal_rawat](https://answers.ros.org/users/35786/vishal_rawat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. You need a full ROS 2 installation.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vishal_rawat](https://answers.ros.org/users/35786/vishal_rawat/) on 2018-06-12**:
Ok...but i thought it gives you an access to all the ROS functionalities and could be downloaded (rclpy) on a non ROS macine and then used to connect to a ROS2 machine ? @William